# text annotation to a graph in ggplot

Tags: r, text, ggplot2

I am drawing a PC plot using ggplots.
I know this question has been answered in some previous posts but I could not still solve my problem.
I have a data set called tab which is the output of PCA

```
     sample.id            pop         EV1         EV2
  HT185_MK8-2.sort.bam   HA_27 -0.03796869 0.046369552
  HT48_SD1A-37.sort.bam  HA_14  0.04208393 0.032961404
  HT53_IA1A-10.sort.bam  HA_1 -0.02580365 0.005262476
  HT260_MK1-4.sort.bam   HA_20 -0.06090545 0.005578504
  HT170_SD2W-14.sort.bam HA_17  0.01288395 0.012117833
  Q093_MK7-13.sort.bam   HA_26  0.06310162 0.188558067
```

I want to add labels on each dot in the plot, theses dots are individuals from several populations. So I want to give them their population ID (pop column in the data set).
I am using something this

```
ggplot(data=tab,aes(EV1,EV2, label=tab[,2])) + geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(pop))) + ylab("Principal component 2") + xlab("Principal component 1")
```

But I do not get my desired output.
This is my PC plot!
So could anyone help me to add population label on each dot in the plot!
Thanks[image]

Comment: What did you do to try to add labels? Which question did you try to follow and where did you get confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `geom_text`:

```
geom_text(aes(label=as.character(pop)),hjust=0,vjust=0)
```

Also consider looking into [plotly](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/), or setting a threshold on the labels, because labeling every point will lead to a very crowded plot, and probably very little additional useful information.